# Use javaScript closure to do sum(a)(b) = a+b and accepts any number of brackets

Tags: javascript

The output for sum(a)(b) = a+b, for instance:

sum(1)(2) = 3

sum(5)(-1)(2) = 6

sum(6)(-1)(-2)(-3) = 0

the aim is to accept any number of input arguments.

I have seen a right solution to this question.
My question is why my method doesn't work.

Right solution:

```
function sum(a){
    var sum = a
    function f(b){
        sum += b
        return f
    }
    f.toString = function(){return sum}
    return f
}
```

My method:

```
function add(a){
    function add1(b){
        if(b === undefined){
            console.log(a);
            return;
        }
        else{
            return add(a+b);
        }
    }

    if(a === undefined){
        console.log(a);
        return;
    }
    else{
        return add1;    
    }
}
```

Test data: add(4),add(4)(2).
In both test cases, branch "a === undefined" or "b === undefined" will never be reached. I'm very confused about this.

Comment: You really don't need the `if(a === undefined){` at all, unless maybe you want to set `a` to a default of `0` on the first call. The only time the caller calls `add` is on the first invocation. After that `add` is only called internally, so the caller always gets `add1` after the first call.

Comment: @Guedes yes, that's the reason. Thanks.

Comment: @squint Yes, `if(a === undefined){` is unnecessary. After i deleted it, i find function `add()` merely return function `add1`, and that's basically the same with the right solution.

Comment: IMO, your solution is a little more interesting than the 'right solution', since yours doesn't require a temporary variable to be mutated when the next call comes. Passing the current sum forward to the `add` function seems cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`In both test cases, branch "a === undefined" or "b === undefined" will never be reached`

That's because a and b are the parameters for functions. To have them undefined you either have to call the function without passing a value for the paramter or passing undefined as value such as `add()` `add(5)()` `add(5)(void(0))`

Your function works, if you add an empty`()` at the end e.g. `add(7)(8)(9)()`.